# Bash: works at command line but getting 'curl: (1) Protocol ""https" not supported or disabled in libcurl' when using in a script

Tags: arrays, json, bash, curl, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Got stuck with the situation that a curl request works fine with the command line but does not work at a script giving weird errors. Here is the part of the script:

```
#we already got the $token
#vars defining curl parameters
dc="NA EU AU SEA JP"
curl_url='https://example.com/api/config/v1/'
curl_request='alertingProfiles?'
curl_properties='tenant=all&stage=prd&cluster='
curl_auth='"Authorization: Bearer '"$token"'"'
for k in $dc; do

        # Download the json for each DC using the curl request
        curl_combined=\""$curl_url$curl_request$curl_properties$k"\"; echo "$curl_combined"
        curlCMD=( -vv --location --request GET "$curl_combined"  -H "$curl_auth" -o \""$k.json"\")
        echo "${curlCMD[@]}"
        curl "${curlCMD[@]}"
        done
```

When I run this in a script I see the following output:
First, the output from the first echo command

```
"https://example.com/api/config/v1/alertingProfiles?tenant=all&stage=prd&cluster=NA"
```

Then, the output from the second echo command which is what curl should take as a parameter, I've skipped the bearer token, but trust me, it is not a problem here.

```
-vv --location --request GET "https://example.com/api/config/v1/alertingProfiles?tenant=all&stage=prd&cluster=NA" -H "Authorization: Bearer " -o "NA.json"
```

And I am getting following output

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
* Protocol ""https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
* Closing connection -1
curl: (1) Protocol ""https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

Please note **two double quotes** in the message above in front of https.

If I simply copy/paste the above second echo output in the command line right after curl and execute, it works as expected and downloads JSON in the file.

If I remove " from `curl_combined` var, the request is sent without double quotes and now I am getting the message `curl: (56) Unexpected EOF` from the script.

If I copy/paste the second echo output (without double quotes), supply it to curl, and execute from the command line, I am getting 403 message until I put double or single quotes around the https request.

In short - it seems that double quotes around the https request is necessary but for some reason, curl does not take it.

So what went wrong here? I don't mind even to write the constructed URL in a file and read from it or use herestring if it helps, but want to know what exactly went wrong here.

Thanks.

P.S. Removing `--location` or `--request GET` or both does not change the outcome.

Comment: you can't evaluate quotes from strings, they are taken as literally chars without any meaning

Comment: Then, what would be the solution here?

Comment: Clarification because SO's error handling "eats" certain characters:

When there is an escaped double quote in front and at the end of ``"$curl_url$curl_request$curl_properties$k"`` -  to have the http request enclosed in double quotes, then I am getting ``Protocol ""https" not supported or disabled in libcurl`` message.
When there are no such escaped double quotes, just ``curl_combined="$curl_url$curl_request$curl_properties$k"``, I am getting ``curl: (56) Unexpected EOF`` message instead.

Hope this clarifies the situation.

Comment: run your script in debugging mode to visualize the problem *bash -x script*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works replacing curl request with array to the following

```
curl -vv \
--location \
--request GET \
"$curl_combined" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer ${token}" \
-o "$k.json"
```

But it is ugly, let's say politely...

Answer (score 1):

The script is using passing the `"${curlCMD[@]}"` array as parameter to `curl`. This approach will handle the correct expansion of the url, regardless of any special characters in it. There is no need to wrap the curl_combined with additional quotes using the `\"` construct.

Suggesting replacing setting curl_combined with:

```
curl_combined="$curl_url$curl_request$curl_properties$k"
echo "$curl_combined"
```

Comment: I did. As I wrote in the question, without double quotes it gives a different error.

Comment: you probably overlooked some quote to remove. update your question, without knowing what exactly you tried it's just guesswork

Comment: No, I did not.
As I said in my question if I have ``curl_combined="$curl_url$curl_request$curl_properties$k"`` this gets ``curl: (56) Unexpected EOF`` message instead of ``Protocol ""https" not supported or disabled in libcurl``.

But now I figured out my own solution.

Comment: Can you share the output of `curl -v` (or the solution) ?